# Google Maps API: Distance Manipulation

Tags: android, google-maps

How do you manipulate the android Google maps API to provide you the distance between two locations you take as an input ? Anyone please help, have been stuck on this for quite a while now ...

Comment: Do you wan't the distance to travel distance or as the crow fly's distance?

Comment: I am actually working on a program that would take in user input of city names and give them the distance and the taxi fare of that distance.

Comment: I am new to android so i haven't tried much yet, I am having trouble understanding it, but just going through the basics right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5B%5D%29) you go. You don't even need the maps api for that, Android has all you need. 
A little googling would have brought you there.

Comment: can you like help me on how to get the longitude and latitude based on the user input ... for example if i want to calculate distance between two locations ... like lets say Location A and Location B ... taking A and B as an input will the longitude and latitude be calculated by itself ?? this question maybe very silly, but i am really new to programming ... so help me out please ? And will the distance be given on driving perspective or the walking perspective ?

Comment: What will the user put in? Latitude and longitude? Or the name of a city?

Comment: You can use this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html class for that, there's lots of tutorials out there on how to use it. This will require you to have some basic understanding of JSON.

Comment: Actually disregard the JSON part. No JSON involved.